# How to show dropdowns for the foreign keys in dynamic data custom Edit template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am using Dynamic data template and have custom "Edit" Page for any entity.
I want the dropdowns for the foreign key as it comes with the default Edit page templates.

I know it may be an easy stupid ques. but still pls let me know How to achieve that?? or let me know the direction to do it..

Thanks!

Comment: I guess its not that stupid quest...plz help

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to autogenerate the filter
[Display(Name = "Course", Order = 20, AutoGenerateField = true, **AutoGenerateFilter** = true)]